# Store a file insde python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

I am not sure what it is called. I have seen a installer program have stored data at the end of the installer script, looked like just a mess of random text, which then got turn into a seperate file upon running the installer. There was some comand that said something like `line xxx -> end | file.txt`. Im so sorry if this makes no sense but if anyone knows what I am looking for id like to do the same thing in a python script. directions to a resource or an explination on how to do it here would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One reason shell scripts do this is that a shell variable cannot contain arbitrary binary data (namely, null bytes). Python variables have no such limitations; just store the data in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

```
    # Create a temporary working directory
    tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

    # Unpack the zipfile into the temporary directory
    pip_zip = os.path.join(tmpdir, "pip.zip")
    with open(pip_zip, "wb") as fp:
        fp.write(b85decode(DATA.replace(b"\n", b"")))
```